# What is the 32 bit binary equivalent of -41.25?

Tags: floating-point, bit

So I'm not sure how to do this, but I'll try. Where do I go wrong?

So I know double has 1 bit for sign, 8 bits for exponent, 23 bits for the fraction.

So since it's negative, it starts with a 1.

41 is equal to 101001 in binary.

0.125 is equal to 1/8 = 1/2^3 = 1 * 2^(-3) = 0.001. Is there an easier way to calculate this?

So combined it is -101001.001 which is -1.01001001 * 2^5

Since the exponent is 5 and the offset is 127 for floating point in the ieee754 standard, then 5 + 127 = 132 which is 10000100 in binary so the representation in 32 bit binary or a double is

```
 1 10000100 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Is that right? OR did I miss something up? Is there an easier way?

Comment: You really need to be much clearer about where you are discussing 32 bit and where you are discussing 64 bit. In IEEE 754 they have different exponent width and bias. You cannot, for example, convert from 32 bit to 64 bit by merely adding some zeros to the fraction field.

Comment: For example, in 32 bit binary, 1.0 is 0x3f80 0000. In 64 bit 1.0 is 0x3ff0 0000 0000 0000.

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to confuse and combine the 32-bit and 64-bit IEEE 754 binary floating point formats. It makes no sense to say "Since the exponent is 5 and the offset is 127 for floating point in the ieee754 standard". The IEEE 754 standard makes it clear that the exponent size and bias both depend on the format. It is true that the exponent is 5 and the bias 127 for 32-bit binary floating point in the IEEE 754 standard, but false for 64-bit binary floating point.

**Common to both 32 bit and 64 bit formats:**

-41.125 is negative, so for both formats I am going to convert 41.125 but set the sign bit to 1.

Decimal 41.125 is binary 101001.001, or 1.01001001 with binary exponent 5.

**32-bit binary float:**

The exponent is 8 bits wide, with bias 127. The exponent field in decimal is 132, binary 10000100.

For normal numbers, there is no need to store the digit before the binary point. It is non-zero, and there is only one non-zero binary digit. The fraction part is 01001001, with trailing zeros to fill to 23 bits.

Combining these gives binary (commas group blocks of four bits, spaces separate fields):

1 100,0010,0 010,0100,1000,0000,0000,0000

hexadecimal 0xc2248000.

**64-bit binary float:**

The exponent is 11 bits wide, with bias 1023.  The exponent field in decimal is 1023+5=1028, binary ‭10000000100‬. The fraction part is 01001001, with trailing zeros to fill to 52 bits.

Combining these gives binary (commas group blocks of four bits, spaces separate fields):

1 ‭100,0000,0100‬, 0100,1001,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000

hexadecimal 0xc044900000000000

**Your questions**

At the end, in addition to the title question, you ask "Is that right? OR did I miss something up? Is there an easier way?".

Your answer is obviously wrong. It has 65 bits, and a correct answer to the title question would have exactly 32 bits, no more and no less.

You may have been trying to calculate the 64-bit representation from the 32 bit representation by adding trailing zeros. That does not work for IEEE 754. There have been floating point systems in which the 64-bit and 32-bit formats differ only in the width of the significand. For sentimental reasons (it was the first floating point system I studied at the bit level), see NCR Century floating point. The formats are described starting on page 65 of [NCR CENTURY 300 PROCESSOR](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ncr/century/RM-0141_Vol1_ProcRef_Apr79/11_Century300_Dec73.pdf). IEEE 754 is different. The width and bias for the exponent differs between the 32 and 64 bit formats.

The 65th bit may have come from switching between using space to separate fields and using space to group digits. That is why this answer uses comma, not space, for grouping.

I believe you are missing the extent of the differences between the 32-bit and 64-bit formats.

However, there is something wrong beyond that. Looking only at the leftmost 32 bits of the result in the question, and comparing to the result in this answer:

```
Q: 1 100,0010,0 001,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000
A: 1 100,0010,0 010,0100,1000,0000,0000,0000
```

The sign and exponent fields match. We both calculated the fraction part of the normalized value as .01001001. The answer has that bit pattern as the leftmost bits of the significand field. The question does not explain how that field was calculated.

The easiest way to do this is to leave it to computers. There are several on-line calculators and converters that will do this for you. The results in this answer were checked against an [IEEE 754 calculator](http://weitz.de/ieee/).